# How to config the Pods project‘s build setting？

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

My iOS project dependent other pod, and I want to change the build setting for Pods project after  execute "pod install".
For example, a pod framework have to set build setting item "allow non modular includes in framework modules" to YES, how could I config it as simple as possible? thanks for all suggustion!

Answer (score 5):

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings["CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES"] = true
    end
  end
end
```

This will modify the setting for project "Pods"

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your pod file:

```
# - POST INSTALL HOOK

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings["CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES"] = true
    end
  end
end
```

This will modify the setting for **all** your targets, if you want a specific one, add an `if` condition as you see fit.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: But it does't work in my project, I pasted it both in and out `target 'TestProject' do end`

Comment: Did you do a `pod install` afterward? And it should be outside any other block.

Comment: Yes， I do a pod install, but it still doesn't work, Could I have a elegant style to do it?